# проверить поле на null и выполнить distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

Здравстуйте, не могу cообразить, как правильно написать запрос.

Вот моя таблица "object":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и данные в ней
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу сделать distinct по полю object_id при условии, что у меня все value is not null у поля с таким же object_id.

т.е., если у всех 6 строк, которые показаны на скрине object_id = 505 и value is not null, то мне выводится одна строка с object_id, а если хотя бы у одной строки value равен null, то ничего не выводится. Как то так, использую postgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы проверить наличие записей необходимо использовать `EXISTS`. Предикат `EXISTS` принимает значение `TRUE`, если подзапрос содержит любое количество строк, иначе его значение равно `FALSE`. Для `NOT EXISTS` все наоборот. Этот предикат никогда не принимает значение `UNKNOWN/NULL`.

```
select distinct
  o.object_id 
from object o
where not exists
  (select
     null
   from object t
   where t.object_id = o.object_id
   and   t.value is null)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если бы мне например ещё нужно было бы проверить value на двойной пробел и если у одной из этих строк был бы двойной пробел, то ничего бы не выводило.

Comment: Все в скобках через `or`. Если равен двум пробелам `(t.value is null or t.value = '  ')`, если содержит `(t.value is null or instr(t.value, '  ') > 0)`

Comment: Alex R. благодарю, очень помог!)